# How can I set default outgoing port and listening port on spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How can I set default outgoing port and listening port for the reply on spring integration?
Is it possible?
I want to do that with tcp technology.

Here is my code:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="${netSocketServer}" port="${netPort}"
    single-use="true" so-timeout="${netSoTimeOut}" />

<int:channel id="input" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="input" reply-channel="reply" connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="${netRequestTimeout}" reply-timeout="${netReplyTimeout}" />


<int:channel id="reply" datatype="java.lang.String" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders support defaults by including a `:1234` part...

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="${netSocketServer}" port="${netPort:1234}"
    single-use="true" so-timeout="${netSoTimeOut}" />
```

EDIT: per the comment below...

The framework doesn't support this out of the box at this time; you need to supply a custom `TcpSocketFactorySupport` to the connection factory (via the `socket-factory-support` attribute) to use the alternative connection strategies (allowing you to set the local port). If you need help, I might be able to post a gist in the next day or so.

I will shortly be starting work on a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-2924) that will make it easier to use some of these features.

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/7341115). Bear in mind that setting the local port is unusual - usually the client side chooses an ephemeral port. The problem with hard-wiring the local port is it will fail to bind if it's in use (or is still in `TIME_WAIT` since it was last used).

Comment: Sorry if I made a mistake explaining the problem. I meant, set a default outgoing port from my computer, the port posted is the server port with its host ip.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was looking for a solution with the data you gave me in order to not disturb you! But your help came faster!  I will try it! thans again!