# How can I solve connections or configuration problems with spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have two environments, in one of them I put my application using spring integration and it works perfectly.
But in the second enviroment when I try to connect with the server, I get a time out error.
I suppose that the error is becouse of a some configuration of the network topology but I not really sure.
I did a test application using spring integration using the  configuration described here:

[How can I set default outgoing port and listening port on spring integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815964/how-can-i-set-default-outgoing-port-and-listening-port-on-spring-integration)

The idea of setting outgoing port is just to control where is going the information.
But this test application failed to connect and throw the same error as my application.
I made a second test, in this case using the usual java classes to create a tcp client, and the test worked fine.
So my suspicions are arround the configuration of spring integration and somesomething with the network too.
Just to contribute with more information, I´m using spring integration 2.2.6

Thanks in advance again!

Comment: When tracking down issues like this, I would suggest using something like wireshark - especially if, as you say, it works with pure java. Compare the network traces. That said, the Spring Integration adapters are using the same classes under the covers. You may be able to debug it by just enabling DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time out errors usually mean that there is a firewall between you and the server. Get the IP addresses and host names involved and visit your network admin.

Comment: It wasn´t the firewall. I was the netbios, I disable it and the connection was successful. But, what´s the diference with spring integration and the common java classes to use a tcp connection? Becouse one test was working and the other failed.

Comment: There should be no difference; eventually all Spring code has to use the networking code of the Java runtime.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in fact, before disabling the netbios all the connections started to work.