# Set default port in server tcp-connection-factory

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is there any way to change the default port of tcp server dynamically?

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpConnectionFactory"
    type="server" port="${defaultport}" single-use="true"
    serializer="tcpSerializerDeserializer"
    deserializer="tcpSerializerDeserializer" />
```

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19816895) but I think it's no good for me. I can try this answer but I don´t know where call for change the port by another from database.

Thanks in advance.